# ASCII to HEX string in Java returns ASCII value and not HEX

Tags: java, hex, ascii

I am trying to convert an ASCII string into HEX. But for some reason, it is giving me back the ASCII value instead of the HEX value.

So here is my code:

```
public String toHex(String strToConvert) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(strToConvert.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
        sb.append(bb.get());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The function call is made like: `toHex("A");`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you expect any conversion to hex to occur? You're basically calling `StringBuilder.append(int)` with each byte in turn. (It's not clear why you're getting `ByteBuffer` involved at all.) `StringBuilder.append(int)` is documented as: "Appends the string representation of the int argument to this sequence.
The overall effect is exactly as if the argument were converted to a string by the method `String.valueOf(int)`, and the characters of that string were then appended to this character sequence." Where does that say anything about a hex conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that converts the byte you are getting from the buffer to hexadecimal; the `sb.append(int)` method that you are calling converts it to decimal, not hexadecimal. One solution is to do this:

```
sb.append(String.format("%02X", bb.get()));
```

Note that you call your method "ASCII to hex", but you are not actually using ASCII - you are using UTF-8, which is not exactly the same as ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02X", char_value))
```